# wp_remote_post and form post

Tags: query-posts, forms, wp-remote-post

Actually it is more general question but now i am trying to use it on wordpress site so I preferred to post it here.

I am trying to understand the difference between remote post and form post.

When I query a string and post it to remote server, I get the result as string and with "print $response" see it on browser console. But I want it to be displayed as html on browser. Am I expecting wrong thing or could i do such thing?

Basically I want to see raw response as html.

**EDIT**

In case of being more expressive..
I am trying to write credit card payment gateway inside woocommerce

Inside process_payment function which is called at the end of customer order, I am posting all info to bank server like below:

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    ....
    ...
    $okUrl = "http://localhost/xxx/wc-api/paymentpos/";         
    $failUrl = "http://localhost/xxx/wc-api/paymentpos/";
    $payload = array(.....);
         $response = wp_remote_post( $environment_url, array(
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'body'      => http_build_query( $payload ),
        'timeout'   => 45,
        'sslverify' => false,
    ) );
    $respbody = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    print $respbody;
    }
```

After that, bank server should reply to payment_callback() which is like

```
public function payment_callback(){

    global $woocommerce;

    wc_add_notice( 'OK', 'success' );
    .....
    exit();     
}
```

I am getting $respbody as below on console.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function moveWindow() {
  document.returnform.submit();
}
</script>  
</head>

<body onLoad="javascript:moveWindow()">
<form action="http://localhost/xxx/wc-api/paymentpos/" method="post" name="returnform">

 <input type="hidden" name="EXTRA.ERTELEMESABITTARIH" value="20121123">
 ....
 <input type="hidden" name="okUrl" value="http://localhost/xxx/wc-api/paymentpos/">
 ...
 <input type="hidden" name="mdStatus" value="2">

 <input type="hidden" name="HASH" value="QZVV9Zfv4tlzi36WJNbLVlbuWY8=">
 <input type="hidden" name="rnd" value="GSZV87rHM+Ol5WDiMbtC">
 <input type="hidden" name="HASHPARAMS" value="clientid:oid:AuthCode:ProcReturnCode:Response:mdStatus:cavv:eci:md:rnd:">
 <input type="hidden" name="HASHPARAMSVAL" value="100200000160451Declined2499850:FE7D7E1062435636DEA77FD3F96CE40C68334FAFE6458F2FC530F26814B29935:4043:##100200000GSZV87rHM+Ol5WDiMbtC">
 ...    

    <!-- To support javascript unaware/disabled browsers -->
    <noscript>
        <center><br>
        Please Click to continue.<br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSbmt"></center>
    </noscript> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
{"result":"failure","messages":"","refresh":"false","reload":"false"}
```

This response should trigger payment_callback() function. Manually I could trigger payment_callback() like http://localhost/xxx/wc-api/paymentpos/. But this response could not trigger. I am suspicious about I could handle wp_remote_post response correctly.

Comment: Please show your code your using and what the expected output should be.

Comment: downvoted as it seems like the main issue here is understanding how payment transactions wrok, and how to debug them. both are not specific to wordpress

Comment: Could you solve this problem?
I have something similar the `$respbody` in test mode returns the parameters correctly, but in production mode it returns HTML code

Answer (score 0):

`wp_remote_get` returns a json string.

You have different function to work with this json response. `wp_remote_head() wp_remote_retrieve_body(), wp_remote_retrieve_header(), wp_remote_retrieve_headers(), wp_remote_retrieve_response_code(), wp_remote_retrieve_response_message()`

The example from the codex:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://www.example.com/index.html' );
  if( is_array($response) ) {
     $header = $response['headers']; // array of http header lines
     $body = $response['body']; // use the content
 }
```

Depending on the page request, the body could be an array or object or HTML. Of course, in case of array or object, there's a need to loop through the results like usually.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you have more control over the [arguments](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API#Other_Arguments) you use in [wp_remote_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post). But because you have more control, the defaults won't always be the same. For example; `User Agent` is usually empty with `wp_remote_post` but uses the browser name when submitting the form in your browser.

When you consume a `POST` request there isn't much difference. It's typically just the `$_GET` or `$_POST` (`$_REQUEST` for either) on the other end that holds key value pairs.